# invalid int input gets stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

```
do
{
    cout << "Enter the numerator and denominator of the first fraction: ";
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the numerator and denominator of the second fraction: ";
    cin >> c >> d;
    cout << endl;
} while (!validNum(a, b, c, d));

...

bool validNum(int num1, int num2, int num3, int num4)
{
    if (cin.fail() || num2 == 0 || num4 == 0)
    {
        if (num2 == 0 || num4 == 0)
        {
            cout << "Invalid Denominator. Cannot divide by 0" << endl;
            cout << "try again: " << endl;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Did not enter a proper number" << endl;
            cout << "try again: " << endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

What I am trying to do is make sure the denominator is not zero and that they only enter numbers. The dividing by zero code works fine but when you enter a char value it enters an infinite loop and do not know why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (cin.fail() ... )
```

Once you enter an invalid value (i.e a `char`), the failbit in the stream will be on and `validNum` will invariably return false, causing an infinite loop.

You need to clear the error state and ignore the rest of the input after each call:

```
if (std::cin.fail())
{
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Comment: Awesome it works perfect. Out of curiosity how does numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max() work and what does it do

Comment: @JuanSierra [`numeric_limits::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max) returns the largest value for a given type.